# Put Correct order in php array_chunk loop row and multiple columns

Tags: php, loops

I have a Array.
Example:

```
$array = array(
    "Row1",
    "Row2",
    "Row3",
    "Row4",
    "Row5",
    "Row6",
    "Row7",
    "Row8",
    "Row9",
    "Row10",
    "Row11",
    "Row12",
    "Row13",
    "Row14",
    "Row15",
    "Row16",
    "Row17",
    "Row18",
    "Row19",
    "Row20",
    "Row21",
    "Row22",
    "Row23",
    "Row24",
    "Row25",
    "Row26",
    "Row27",
    "Row28",
);

$columns = 6;

$modified_array = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / $columns) );
```

And i have an foreach like this

```
foreach ($modified_array as $key => $value) {

}
```

My array chung divide my array in 6 columns and a i have in loop row 3 diferents columns layout and i want repeat this every loop row.

I have some condition to stop in key value of my foreach to show diferent column but loop dont work very well and i cant all my itens of my array

See my Print [Imagem Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLkLB.png)
Or my Test php code [Php Example](http://main.xfiddle.com/code_73079445.php)

I want every row of my loop must have same order of my array.

Full code of my foreach:

```
foreach ($modified_array as $key => $value) {
if($key == 0 || $key % 2 == 0){
    $html.= '<div class="row" style=""> <strong>Line '.$key.'</strong><br>';

    $html.= '
    <div class="col-md-6" style="">
    Column  1
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#21e934; height:175px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x175" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <!--col-md-12-->
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#3c6040; height:175px; color:#FFF">text row Key:: '.$key.' value: '.$value[0].'</div>
        <!--col-md-12-->
    </div>
    <!--col-md-6-->';

    $html.= '
    <div class="col-md-6" style="">
        Column  2';

    $html.= '
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#bb1ff5; height:170px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#bb1717; height:170px; color:#fff">text row Key: '.$key.' value: '.$value[1].'</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right" style="background-color:#f5651f; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/278x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>';

        $html.= '
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#3c6040; height:170px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5651f; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/278x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5ac1f; height:170px; color:#fff">text row Key: '.$key.' value: '.$value[2].'</div>
        </div>';
        $html.= '
    </div>
    <!--col-md-6-->
    </div>';
}


if($key == 1 || $key % 2 == 1){
    $html.= '
    <div class="row" style=""><strong>Line '.$key.'</strong><br>


    <div class="col-md-6" style="">
    Column  3';


    $html.= '
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#3c6040; height:170px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5ac1f; height:170px;">text row Key: '.$key.' value: '.$value[0].'</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5651f; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/278x170" class="img-responsive"></div>

    </div>
    <!--col-md-12-->

    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#bb1ff5; height:170px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5651f; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/278x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:#f5ac1f; height:170px;">text row Key: '.$key.' value: '.$value[1].'</div>
    </div>
    <!--col-md-12-->

</div>
<!--col-md-6-->

<div class="col-md-6" style="">
    Column  4';

    $html.= '
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#21e934; height:175px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/555x175" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#3c6040; height:175px; color:#FFF">text row Key:: '.$key.' value: '.$value[2].'</div>
</div>
<!--col-md-6-->

    </div>
    <!--row-->

    ';

}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Please include relevant code directly in your question, not on 3rd-party sites. Also, I honestly have no idea what you mean by "I want every color row i have one item of my array with same order."

Comment: @PatrickQ how format code like this?

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry for my bad english, i try to sad

"I want my loop itens of my array have a same order of my array."

Comment: it's because you are using boostrap and its classes , responsive instruction put your divs in column , so try to do it without bootstrap formatting before et after add boostrap classes on your divs

Comment: @Fky is i want in boostrap. but the problem is, if you see my php example on Line 1 the value Should be and start with array value Row4..

I edit my post with full code of my foreach

Answer (score 0):

first simplify your if statement

```
if($key % 2 == 0) {
 // your code for odd index
}else {
 // your code for even index
}
```

Next , your chunk gives to you 4 items and your are using only 3, so try to chunk by 3 and let me know

```
$modified_array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

Comment: In my array chuck every row or key i have 4 rows to put in diferent columns if you see my example you must see

http://main.xfiddle.com/code_73079445.php

Comment: So you have to use $value[3] and add relative html to it.. your are using $value[0], $value[1], $value[2] but not $value[3]

Comment: i think you have reason, the problem is in chunk number.

Comment: @IvoBarbosa yes ;)

Comment: I've been on this for two days to get this up and running and it seems the problem was easy to solve.

Comment: @IvoBarbosa sometimes the solution is not far ;)

Comment: if i have a multidimensional array How do I access values ​​by key?